# Unable to Close my Session Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, httpsession

I am unable to close my session using session.invalidate() in my logout method please help!

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    response.getWriter().println("<h3><a href='/assign2'>Logged out Successfully</a></h3>");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if(session!=null)
    session.invalidate();


}
```

the username does not get written to null at all

here's my welcome page to where i am redirecting it

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);

    if(session!=null)
    {
        if((request.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("userid")) != null)
        {
            username = request.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("userid").toString();
        }

    }


    System.out.println(username);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logoff page is OK, but in the welcome page you are mixing concepts:

Altough the execution of `session.invalidate` does unbind all the bound attributes, you are retrieving attribute `userid` from the ServletContext, not the Session. Besides, note that `request.getSession()` creates a new session if necessary.

The coherent way to store and retrieve attributes would be through the HttpSession object:

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);

if(session!=null)
{
    if((session.getAttribute("userid")) != null)
    {
        username = session.getAttribute("userid").toString();
    }
}
System.out.println(username);
```